# How to disable android native debugger in Android studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk, lldb

Using  Studio 2.3, gradle:2.2.1

When I try to attached debugger to app, it shows Android Hybrid Debugger ->

> Now Launching Native Debug Session Attention! No symbol directories
>   found - please check your native debug

Start hybrid debugger. 
And loading all *.so libraries.

I try to rename Android `sdk/lldb` to `lldb_bak` but still starting hybrid debugger.

It takes too long, waste of time. Mean while app is not responding. Can any one help me to disable native debugging. I need only java debugging.

**Edit:**
After uninstalling LLDB from sdk tools Android Studio ask me for Quick fix dialog saying "C++ debugger is missing". If I press yes. It install LLDB again and if I press no it gives me error saying.

> Error running Android Hybrid Debugger (23533): C++ debugger package is
>   missing or incompatible

By the way I am using wireless debugging and I have c++ module with sources in my project.

Changing run configuration ->  "Debug type" to 'Java' doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I found solution. Select Java from debugger list. Enjoy. Sometime it happens :)

[image]

Comment: That solution is very helpful, but it works when you connect to an already running process. I don't see how to do it for the common case of starting from the debugger - i.e. you click on the debugger icon, which causes a build (if needed) and then starts the process and then attaches the debugger.

Comment: @JohnMoore Did you find solution?

Comment: This still launches the native debugger for me from time to time.

Comment: @JohnMoore Its better to attach debugger after running the app instead of starting with debugger. I feel it's fast to attach then start with debugger. So for me this is totally fine.

Answer (score 28):

For the ones still looking for a permanent solution:

[image: run debug configuration window in android studio 4.1.3]

Go to menu **Run**, then **Edit Configurations**. Under **Debugger** then select the *Debug Type* **Java**.